# Having trouble animating fragment in and out

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my game, when the user presses the back button, it should bring up the pause menu (as a fragment). When the user presses the back button again, it should close the pause menu. All of this should be done with animations.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (!paused)
    {
        // pause game here

        if (mPauseFragment == null)
        {
            mPauseFragment = new PauseFragment();

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            ft.replace(R.id.pause_container, mPauseFragment, "pauseFragment");
            // Start the animated transition.
            ft.commit();
        }
        else
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(mPauseFragment).commit();
        }           
    }
    else
    {
        // resume game here
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(mPauseFragment).commit();
    }

    paused = !paused;
}
```

It fades in just fine (but only once), but it doesn't fade out at all. Please give me a bit of hand, thanks.

Comment: this statement is not clear and specific- "It doesn't seem to work the way I intend it to be"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ft.setCustomAnimations` gets applied to only that particular fragment transaction. Set your animation to every show hide transaction.